# App Roles in Azure Web API

Tags: azure, azure-app-api

I am getting following error when trying to acquire a token for my Azure Web API.

**ADAL Error Occurred: AADSTS50105:** The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application 'app guid'.

I don't have any app roles in my manifest and I don't need one. What is causing the check for app roles. I don't have it enabled at the Azure AD Application level as well.

Comment: I've found more users facing the same problem in here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/463

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. There is a problem with ADAL.js. It was giving a fake error. I had an issue with using Url while requesting for token. I saw while saving token the ADAL.js uses the client id of the app. As I was using the URL, the token was not found and instead of conveying the correct error, it was reporting roles issue.

Comment: @NitinRastogi were you able to resolve this issue? ADAL.js was using the client id instead of the token? Any advice would be helpful, I am also seeing this error, and suspect it is not being reported correctly (users are in a group assigned to the application in Azure). Thank you!